# How to add a local non-maven project as a dependency for a maven project?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I created a new Spring web app, and I'd very much like to use Maven to handle builds/dependencies.  My problem is that the project depends on some existing local projects, and mavenizing them is not currently an option.  Is it possible to depend on these projects without mavenizing them?

Comment: Try this, http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

Comment: Are the existing local projects built with Ant, another command-line build tool, or are they "built" and "released" using an IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and you shouldn't try that. Maven's main goal is to have a standardized build. This is what makes Maven so easy to use: Exceptions aren't be the norm. That's why Maven requires that all dependencies are in the typical Maven format (POM + jar).

When you say "mavenizing them is not currently an option", you basically say "Maven is not currently an option". In my experience, converting an existing project to Maven just takes a couple of minutes ... unless said project uses a messy, unreliable build process in which case you really *should* convert it to Maven ASAP just to stop wasting even more of your precious time. :-)

If everything else fails, use a build server to produce JAR files from the dependent projects and deploy them to a company wide repository server or just to your local machine.

Comment: I completely agree that our entire codebase should be using Maven, and it eventually will, but right now the powers-that-be want to see my new project by the end of the week, while Mavenzing dozens of projects and testing them will take quite some time.

Answer (score 10):

I think that the easiest way to do this is to deploy your local dependency to your local repository so that maven can use it as regular dependency.

To deploy local `jar` file into local repository use command line like:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<MY-FILE> -DgroupId=MY-GROUP-ID -DartifactId=MY-ARGIFACT -Dversion=MY-VERSION -Dpackaging=jar
```

If you have shared repository like Artifactory in your company you can deploy the jar there. Otherwise each developer will have to deploy in into his local repository. The good news it must be done only once.

EDIT.

Here is a way to define project-to-project dependency into `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.util</groupId>
        <artifactId>util</artifactId>
        <version>${com.mycompany.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

That's it. Util is just yet another project into my workspace.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having to archive the local projects?  New code is pushed to them fairly regularly, and I'd hate to have to continuously re-jar the projects and install them in the local repository.

Comment: If you are speaking about local projects it is even simpler. Use project-to-project dependencies into your pom.xml. I will post example as an addition to my answer in a minute.

Comment: This is an awesome answer and does exactly what I need it to in just a coupla key strokes and clicks.

Comment: I don't understand the alternative option. This is how you make a dependency on Maven projects. How does that even help? My non-maven project does not have a groupId, artifactId and version.

Comment: @AlexR Is your UTIL project a Maven project or non Maven project ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer's a tad late but just in case somebody needs it, I found the solution using Maven's [Build Helper Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html), that is if you don't want deploying your non-maven project as a jar:

So basically you just add the source directory of the non-maven project in the `<sources>` tag:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>C:\Users\user123\eclipse-workspace\my_non_maven_project\src</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now if that non-maven project has dependencies of its own, you need to add them in the `<dependencies>` section of your maven project as well.