# How to reference a java project in an eclipse maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two java projects in eclipse. One is maven enabled, the another one is just a normal java project. I want my maven project to reference the java project on build path.

My question is, Any simple way to reference the java project without changing it to a maven project ?

Firstly, i know that i can export the project as a jar and then maven install it. Then i can reference it in the dependency section of pom.xml. This is not dynamic enough to suit my needs.

Is there a maven plugin that can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a local non-maven project as a dependency for a maven project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163153/how-to-add-a-local-non-maven-project-as-a-dependency-for-a-maven-project)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven compile with multiple src directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose  It could be a duplicate. What i am asking is any alternative to fix the problem instead of mavenizing it (out of my control) or mvn install (time consuming). I hope you understand it is not waste to ask for this question.

Comment: @Tommy The link I posted provides a configuration you can use on your Mavenized project to "import" the sources of the other regular project. I understand that is your goal. If not, tell me more details.

Comment: @Arturo Tena It is a solutions but not perfect. That project has a user library that has a lot of jar files inside. It would be great if i can directly reference the project. I would accept it if there isn't any new idea. Thanks for the help =)

Comment: @Tommy I see. The other project consist solely on JARs?

Comment: @Arturo Tena Yup, only user library and src/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22300875) to "import" the JARs, and the link ([Maven compile with multiple src directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270445/maven-compile-with-multiple-src-directories)) for the source. That way the project will remain pure Maven. Let me know if Eclipse has some issue with this solution.