# Reference a directory in maven to add local jars to exported war file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using maven to build my project, I also have some .jar libraries that I cannot include in my POM because I don't know their arifact and group IDs. Is it possible to add a directory as a repository, or just reference them in my pom in another way, so that when I export .war file they get packaged?

Comment: you can add them to your classpath the old way. they should still be packed into whatever you pack it

Comment: they are added to classpath and they are not being packed

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163153/how-to-add-a-local-non-maven-project-as-a-dependency-for-a-maven-project) probably it helps you